# Saving timer with local storage and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, timer, storage, local

I'm having an issue trying use local storage values to save a timer on a webpage, navigate to another page, then start the timer again from the values saved from clicking off the initial page.

I have the seconds to work but struggling with the minutes and hours, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I can input the saved minutes and hours values into the formula, but since the formula dynamically updates every second it doesn't work correctly.

Any help on this would be really appreciated, thanks.

Here is the code:

```
var secondtime = localStorage.getItem("Seconds");
var minutetime = localStorage.getItem("Minutes");
var hourtime = localStorage.getItem("Minutes");
var sec = localStorage.getItem("Seconds");

setInterval( function(){

document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML=pad(++sec%60);
document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML=pad(parseInt(sec/60,10));
document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML=pad(parseInt(sec/6000,10));
}, 1000);

function SaveTime() {
    localStorage.setItem("Seconds", $("#seconds").text())
    localStorage.setItem("Minutes", $("#minutes").text())
    localStorage.setItem("Hours", $("#hours").text())
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
$("#seconds").text(secondtime);
$("#minutes").text(minutetime);
$("hours").text(hourtime);

<div class="Bottom_Bar">

<p class="c1" id="seconds_text"><span id="seconds">00</span></p>

<p class="c1" id="minutes_text"><span id="minutes">00</span></p>

<p class="c1" id="hours_text"><span id="hours">00</span></p>

<div class="Button">
 <a href="NextPage.html"> onclick="SaveTime()</div>
```

Comment: re-read carefully : var hourtime = localStorage.getItem("Minutes");  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

First thing i'd like to bring to your notice is that you are trying to assign minuts to hourTime variable too take a look at you initialization

```
var hourtime = localStorage.getItem("Minutes");
```

And below is the simple code which store and retrieves time from local storage

```
<a href="#" onclick="SaveTime()">Save Current Time</a> | 
<a href="#" onclick="retrieveTime()">Retrieve Saved Time</a>

<div id="result"></div>

function SaveTime(){
    var date = new Date();
    var timeObj = { sec:date.getSeconds(), min:date.getMinutes(), hr:date.getHours() };
    localStorage.setItem("timeObj", JSON.stringify(timeObj));
    $('#result').append(JSON.stringify(timeObj)+' -- > Saved<br />' );
}

function retrieveTime(){
    var timeObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("timeObj"));
    //You have the time with you now
    $('#result').append(timeObj.hr+':'+timeObj.min+':'+timeObj.sec+' --> Retrieved<br />');
}
```

[Here is JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mujahid095ads/NxQ8v/)